# Is their any way to convert exponential number string to original number

Tags: vb.net

My original number is '250000120001000' but it is converted into '2.5000012E+014'

I want the original number that is '250000120001000'.

It is imported from Excel to a DataTable.

Is there any way in VB.NET?

Comment: Please edit the question to add the code which results in it being shown as '2.5000012E+014'.

Comment: It's not a conversion. It's just a number format. Change the format from "General" to "0".

Answer (score 0):

Use Double.Parse(String) and .ToString("E11"). The 11 after the E determins the number of digits after the decimal point. If Excel has truncated the exponential number I am not sure if the underlying number is still there.

```
 Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim x = 250000120001000
    Dim y = x.ToString("E11")
    Debug.Print(y) 'Prints 2.50000120001E+014
    Dim z = Double.Parse(y)
    Debug.Print(z.ToString) 'Prints 250000120001000
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it return '250000120000000'. it Convert all last digit to Zero.

Comment: I see. The problem is converting Original Number to Exponential number. not Exponential number to Double.

Comment: Exponential number Come from Excel. when i Import data from Excel to Data Table.

Comment: You may have to use Office Automation to get at the actual number. I am not sure how to do it with ADO.net

Comment: I did find this in Excel help. "A number format does not affect the actual cell value that Excel uses to perform calculations. The actual value can be seen in the formula bar."

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Excel spreadsheet. I have typed 250000120001000 into cell A2.
[image]
It automatically changed to scientific notation but as you can see it still contains the underlying value.

I run this code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim strFileName = "C:\Users\***\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"
    Dim comText = "Select FirstColumn From [Sheet1$]"
    Dim strCon As String = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={strFileName};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(strCon),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(comText, cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

and the result is

[image]

As you can see it produces the underlying value in the DataGridView without any special processing.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But it works only Column Contains only numeric value. But when i take mix datatype data into single column then it raise same issue. For Example : I take ABCD into first row and in second row i take number then it give me same value that is 2.5E+14.